# Filtering on a large number (hundreds) of conditions

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a largish dataframe (5.5M rows, four columns). The first column (let's call it column A) has 235 distinct entries. The second column (B) has 100 distinct entries, integers from 0 to 99, all present in various proportions for each entry in A.
I groupby on A an aggregate by randomly selecting a value from B. Something like

```py
df.groupby("A").agg(
    pl.col("B").unique().apply(np.random.choice)
)
```

In doing so, every value in A is attributed a random integer. My goal is to select, from the dataframe, the columns C et D corresponding to the pairs A, B so generated.

My approach so far is

```py
choice = df.groupby("A").agg(
    pl.col("B").unique().apply(np.random.choice)
).to_numpy()
lchoice = ((df["A"] == arr[0]) & (df["B"] == arr[1]) for arr in choice)
mask = functools.reduce(operator.or_, lchoice)
sdf = df[mask].select(["C", "D"])
```

It does the job, but does not feel very idiomatic.

My first attempt was

```py
sdf = df.filter(functools
                .reduce(operator.or_,
                        [(pl.col("A") == arr[0]) & (pl.col("B") == arr[1])
                         for arr in choice]))
```

but it hangs until I kill it (I waited for ~30 minutes, while the other approach takes 1.6 seconds).

```py
df.filter(
    (pl.col("period") == choice[0, 0]) & (pl.col("exp_id") == choice[0, 1])
)
```

works fine, as expected, and I have used the `functools.reduce` construct successfully as argument to filter in the past. Obviously, I do not want to write them all by hand; I could loop over the rows of `choice`, filter `df` one at a time and then concatenate the dataframes, but it sounds much more expensive than it should be.

Any tip on getting to my `sdf` "the polars way", without having to create temporary objects, arrays, etc.? As I said, I have a working solution, but it is kind of shaky, and I am interested in learning better polars.

---

EDIT: some mock data

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1.3, 8.9, 6.7]*3 + [3.6, 4.1]*2,
                   "B": [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*3 + [1]*2 + [2]*2,
                   "C": [21.5, 24.3, 21.8, 20.8, 23.6, 15.6, 23.5,
                         16.1, 15.6, 14.8, 14.7, 23.8, 20.],                   
                   "D": [6.9, 7.6, 6.4, 6.2, 7.6, 6.2,
                         6.3, 7.1, 7.8,7.7, 6.5, 6.6, 7.1]})
```

Slight twist on the accepted answer:

```py
df.sort(by=['A', 'B'], in_place=True)
sdf = (df
       .join(df
             .groupby('A', maintain_order=True)
             .agg(pl.col('B')
                  .unique()
                  .sort()
                  .shuffle(seed)
                  .first()
                  .alias('B')),   
             on=['A', 'B'])
       .select(['C','D']))
```

I need to perform this operation multiple time, and I'd like to ensure reproducibility of the random generation, hence the sorts and `maintain_order=True`.

Comment: Could you add some data to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can accomplish what you need with a `join`.

Let's see if I understand your question.  Let's start with this data:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a"] * 2,
        "B": [1, 2, 3, 2] * 3,
        "C": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] * 2,
        "D": ["x", "y", "y", "x"] * 3,
    }
).sort(["A", "B"])
print(df)
```

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ y   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Next, we randomly select a value for B for every value of A.

I'm going to change your code slightly to eliminate the use of numpy and instead use Polars' `shuffle` expression.  This way, we get a Polars DataFrame back, which we'll use in the upcoming join.  (The documentation for the shuffle expression is [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.shuffle.html#polars.Expr.shuffle).  It uses numpy if no seed is provided.)

```py
choice_df = df.groupby("A").agg(pl.col("B").unique().shuffle().first())
print(choice_df)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ b   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

If I understand your question correctly, we now want to get the values for columns C and D in the original dataset that correspond to the three combinations of A and B that we selected in the previous step.  We can accomplish this most simply with a `join`, followed by a `select`. (The select is merely to eliminate columns A and B from the result).

```py
df.join(choice_df, on=['A','B']).select(['C','D'])
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 6   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ x   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ y   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ x   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Does this accomplish what you need?  The resulting code is clean, concise, and typical of the use of the Polars API.

Comment: It does the job perfectly, down to 120 ms from 1.6 s. I did not think of join, cheers!